# Is it possible to install developed applications(xap)into device anywhere devices

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-7, mobile-devices

I would like to test the Application developed for wp7. Is it possible to directly deploy the xap into a device anywhere device or is there any other procedure to do so? 
Is it possible to just transfer the xap file to the zune interface and then to the device anywhere device?

Answer (score 1):

To install an application onto a device using any means other than the official Marketplace is currently only possible to developer unlocked devices. To developer unlock a device you must be a registered developer on the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com), which then enables you to unlock 3 devices.

When the Mango update of the operating system is released later this year (November-ish), there will be two additional deployment options for doing private distribution of certified paid or free apps, or for doing 90-day (maximum) beta testing of free applications. Neither of these options will require a developer unlocked device.